# Put parameters into array and print the even ones

Tags: bash

For my bash script, I need to do 4 things, make the output say "Name of the script:" and the name.
"# Parameters:" and the amount.
Put given parameters into an array.
Print the one's on even positions.

I have managed to do all of these but in a pretty static way, so I was wondering if there's a more dynamic way of doing this?

My current code:

```
echo "Name of the script: $0"
echo "# paramters: $#"
array1=($1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 $10 $11 $12)
echo $2 $4 $6 $8 $10 $12
```

Comment: Hint, `if ((index % 2 == 0)); then echo "even"; fi`. Also, the first index in an array is 0, so you're actually printing the values at the odd indexes in your example.

Comment: For step three you can do `array1=( "$@" )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two first lines are fine (except for the typo):

```
echo "Name of the script: $0"
echo "# paramters: $#"
```

### Option 1

Then to print the even ones (without putting them in an array):

```
while (($#)); do
    shift
    (($#)) && printf "%s\n" "$1"
    shift
done
```

Your parameters are already set as *positional parameters*. The builtin [`shift`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-shift) translates all these parameters, discarding the first one. So we shift and print the first and shift and repeat until there are no more parameters.

### Option 2

You *really* want to put your parameters in an array. Proceed like so:

```
array=( "$@" )
```

(note the quotes and the use of the special variable `$@`). Then you can loop through all the indices of array and print the fields corresponding to even ones (well, odd ones since the numbering of the fields start at `0`):

```
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
    ((i%2==1)) && printf "%s\n" "${array[i]}"
done
```

or use a C-style loop

```
for ((i=1;i<${#array[@]};i+=2)); do
    printf "%s\n" "${array[i]}"
done
```

(I like Option 1 better!).

Comment: The array had to happen.
Your first solution in your Option 2 worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you like Option 1 better? To me it slightly obfuscates what the loop is doing, whereas either variant of option 2 should be clear to everyone.

Comment: @BroSlow I don't see any obfuscation in Option 1. I think of the positional parameters as a stack (think reverse polish as in, e.g., PostScript) and I'm popping my arguments from the stack. In Option 2, it feels awkward to copy all that data in an auxiliary array... for pretty much nothing.